# Is there a way to access process instance from process builder?

Tags: apex, workflow, process-builder, approval-process

I have an approval process on a custom object. Once the approval is approved or reject I want to copy the comments provided part of approval process to the custom object. 
I know I can achieve this using apex but just wondering if this is something can be achieved using process builder as it allows to trigger the approval process so just thinking if there is any way to access the process instance record related to current custom object and read the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't. As you said yourself, only achievable with Apex.

If we could create processes on the approval process record itself, then it probably would be possible, but we can't.